# Selecting all data from a default table size VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, range, selection

I have a spread sheet with a default table size and layout that is populated by information from another spread sheet. This table will always have the same number of columns, but the number of entries in the rows can vary. I want to select all the data from the table, and paste it into another sheet, without copying any empty rows.

My initial attempt involved the following code:

```
Set rightcell = Range("B9").End(x1Right)
Set bottomcell = Range(rightcell).End(x1Down)
```

To define what the bottom right corner should be, so I can reference the entire table like so:

```
Range("B9", bottomcell).Select
```

Or copy or whatever. When I run this, it gives me a "user-defined or object-defined error" and I don't know why. I have the code entered as part of a larger sub, and I have defined my variables as both ranges and variants to try and get this to work. I have spent quite a bit of time scouring the internet for a solution, but so far the information I've found has not explicitly related to my problem, and none of the similar solutions work.

Does anyone know what the appropriate coding for this is, or if I am making some minor error that is throwing everything else off? I remember encountering the same issue during a project in college, but for the life of me, I can't recall the solution. It's quite frustrating.

Also, if I am too vague or you need more clarification on the task, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: An important note that I left out is that the the table I want to extract data from is in the middle of a page with multiple other tables that I am not trying to interact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table will always be in the same location on the sheet, you can do something like this to copy the entire table:

```
'Modify this to any cell in your table (like the top left hand cell):
Range("B9").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("TheSheetYouWantToPasteTo").Range("A1")
```

Even if the table's location on the sheet changes, you can still use the above code to copy the table as long as you know one of the cells in the table.

If you want to keep the same method as you're trying, try this instead:

```
Dim rightcell As Long
Dim bottomcell As Long

'Finds the furthest column to the right:
rightcell = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Finds the bottom most row in the table (will stop at the first non-blank cell it finds.)
bottomcell = Range("B:B").Find("*", Range("B9"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Reference the variables like this:
Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(bottomcell, rightcell)).copy _
Sheets("TheSheetYouWantToPasteTo").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out almost perfectly.

I'm not sure why, but I had to change the bottomcell search line to a different column in order to actually find the last row. Does that function search from the top of the spreadsheet, or from the specified range (B9 in this case)?

Comment: Good, I'm glad it suits your purpose! The `.Find` function here searches the sheet from bottom to top; the top being B9. So if there's a table below the table you're trying to copy, the `.Find` function will stop at that table instead. (The * symbol is looking for ANY charactes in a cell.)

Comment: While `.Find` is more robust (IMO), you could use this instead: `bottomcell = Range("B9").End(xlDown).Row`.

Comment: There is data underneath the table I am wanting to extract data from. However, when I try to use 'End(x1Down)', I am receiving Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Do I need to adjust my variable definitions?

EDIT: I adjusted your original code like so: 'bottomcell = Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A37"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row' where A37 is the last cell in the default table area. This returned exactly what I am looking for. It appears to register that cell as the bottom of the range being searched? Am I misunderstanding the code, or is that correct?

Comment: Did you use `xlDown` or `x1Down`? `xlDown` should work just fine (tested). Using `.Find` that way will work if there aren't any tables below `A37`. You can also play around with `.CurrentRegion.Address`, which will give you the top left and bottom right cell addresses or your table.

Comment: I think I was using `x1Down`, but `xlPrevious` seems to work fine as I have it coded above. I will toy around with `xlDown` to see what is the best syntax for my program. As a separate problem, I need to paste only the values of the copied cells; is there a specific way to do that uisng `.Copy`? I'm having trouble implementing `PasteSpecial`, as I found as solutions elsewhere. Any idea how I might fix that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the issue! I was incorrectly using `x1PasteSpecial` instead of `xlPasteSpecial`.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use

```
Public Function last_row() As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l_row As Long
    'my sheet has 35 columns change this number to fit your
    For i = 1 To 35
        If Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row > l_row Then
            l_row = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next i
    last_row = l_row
End Function
```

Then Use

```
Dim l_row As Long
l_row = last_row
'Again since you know the last column change 35 here to your value 
'or use the String i.e. "AI"
Range("B9", Cells(l_row,35)).Select
```

This will look at every column to determine the the last row that contains data

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to add a crucial detail: An important note that I left out is that the the table I want to extract data from is in the middle of a page with multiple other tables that I am not trying to interact with.